# Can I add animation like this to a border of a button in pure css?

Tags: html, css, animation, border

In this codepen what's animated is a div, https://codepen.io/kevinmcullen/pen/PVmwVz?editors=1100&fbclid=IwAR0IY6EsrDj-lMs_U11ys6npbqsKd1KB5guTkMG6xCAA0GEW9_jlTwMF0Yc

```
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="border"></div>
    <div class="main-element"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

in my code it looks like this

Is there even a chance of making animated border like this on a button?

https://codepen.io/paulshepherd/pen/YzqyYZw

```
<ul>
          <li>
            
                <button class="programming active1">Programming
                  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                </button>
                
                <div class="dropdown-container" style="display: block;" >
```

I've also tried to use this code but I have a problem with converting it to css.

In this example a tag is used as a button

https://codepen.io/ARS/pen/vEwEPP

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/ARS" target="_blank"><span>button</span></a>
```

Comment: please @Paweł Owczarek  this codepen : https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/abNvLMy

Comment: https://codepen.io/Rayeesac/pen/WNvyQrw

Comment: Thank you @RayeesAC! I've been looking for a solution like this for few days, could you please guide me where can I learn about how to manage the look of this animation? I'd like to personalize it a bit more:)